Transfer function mesh analysis
I am stuck with this problem. I simplified my answers using Mathway, and the answer in the book is different. Any help will be appreciated.
My solution:


I also don't understand how the book is able to put Vi(s) in its answer when I use Cramer's Rule with respect to Dy; we don't use the top part.
Solution of the book:


Your question is thorough, so +1.

I agree that \$1\:\text{H}\$ in parallel with \$1\:\text{F}\$ does yield the impedance given in the book's simplification: \$\frac{s}{s^2+1}\$. And I see you also get it, as well, right away in your work. So we are all on the same page for Figure P 2.5(b), on that point.
I very much prefer using symbols than values; only substituting in values later on. This helps me to avoid mistakes. So your schematic in my mind becomes:

With that, then Figure P 2.5(b) mesh, clockwise and starting at the lower left-hand corner of each loop, provides:
$$\begin{align*}
0\:\text{V}+V_{i\left(s\right)}-Z_1\cdot \left(I_{1\left(s\right)}-I_{3\left(s\right)}\right)-Z_2\cdot \left(I_{1\left(s\right)}-I_{2\left(s\right)}\right)&=0\:\text{V}
\\\\
0\:\text{V}-Z_2\cdot \left(I_{2\left(s\right)}-I_{1\left(s\right)}\right)-Z_4\cdot \left(I_{2\left(s\right)}-I_{3\left(s\right)}\right)-Z_5\cdot I_{2\left(s\right)}&=0\:\text{V}
\\\\
0\:\text{V}-Z_3\cdot I_{3\left(s\right)}-Z_4\cdot \left(I_{3\left(s\right)}-I_{2\left(s\right)}\right)-Z_1\cdot \left(I_{3\left(s\right)}-I_{1\left(s\right)}\right)&=0\:\text{V}
\end{align*}$$
Or the following:
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
Z_1+Z_2&-Z_2&-Z_1\\\\
-Z_2&Z_2+Z_4+Z_5&-Z_4\\\\
-Z_1&-Z_4&Z_1+Z_3+Z_4
\end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix}
I_{1\left(s\right)}\\\\
I_{2\left(s\right)}\\\\
I_{3\left(s\right)}
\end{matrix}\right] =
 \left[\begin{matrix}
V_{i\left(s\right)}\\\\
0\:\text{V}\\\\
0\:\text{V}
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
Which, after substitution, matches your matrix. So we are still at the same place.
So, before I bother any further, let's just solve these three equations using a solver. In this case, I'll use Python/SymPy (freely available tools):
EQ1 = Eq( 0 + VI - Z1*(I1-I3) - Z2*(I1-I2), 0 )
EQ2 = Eq( 0 - Z2*(I2-I1) - Z4*(I2-I3) - Z5*I2, 0 )
EQ3 = Eq( 0 - Z3*I3 - Z4*(I3-I2) - Z1*(I3-I1), 0 )
ANS = solve([ EQ1, EQ2, EQ3 ], [ I1, I2, I3 ])

At this point, I'd like the transfer function. So this will be \$\frac{V_{o\left(s\right)}}{V_{i\left(s\right)}}=\frac{I_{2\left(s\right)}\,\cdot\,Z_5}{V_{i\left(s\right)}}\$. So let the solver tell us what that is:
simplify((ANS[I2]*Z5/VI).subs({ Z1:s, Z2:s/(s**2+1), Z3:s, Z4:1, Z5:1/s }))
(s**2 + 2*s + 2)/(s**4 + 2*s**3 + 3*s**2 + 3*s + 2)

This exactly matches with the textbook result.
Let's set up the matrices needed to apply Cramer's Rule:
D = Matrix([ [ Z1+Z2, -Z2, -Z1 ], [ -Z2, Z2+Z4+Z5, -Z4 ], [ -Z1, -Z4, Z1+Z3+Z4 ] ])
C = Matrix([ [VI], [0], [0] ])
D2 = D.copy()
D2[:,1] = C

That provides us enough, as \$I_{2\left(s\right)}=\frac{\det\left(D_2\right)}{\det\left(D\right)}\$. So this means that \$\frac{V_{o\left(s\right)}}{V_{i\left(s\right)}}=\frac{\frac{\det\left(D_2\right)}{\det\left(D\right)}\,\cdot\,Z_5}{V_{i\left(s\right)}}\$.
Let's try that out:
simplify((det(D2)/det(D)*Z5/VI).subs({ Z1:s, Z2:s/(s**2+1), Z3:s, Z4:1, Z5:1/s }))
(s**2 + 2*s + 2)/(s**4 + 2*s**3 + 3*s**2 + 3*s + 2)

Well, at least Cramer's Rule functions as expected and the result matches, yet again.
So this tells me that you made a mistake applying Cramer's or else you messed up the following algebra. One or the other.
Let's look at the result you should get for \$\det\left(D\right)\$:
simplify((det(D)).subs({ Z1:s, Z2:s/(s**2+1), Z3:s, Z4:1, Z5:1/s }))
(s**4 + 2*s**3 + 3*s**2 + 3*s + 2)/(s**2 + 1)

This does not match your result.
How about for \$\det\left(D_2\right)\$?
simplify((det(D2)).subs({ Z1:s, Z2:s/(s**2+1), Z3:s, Z4:1, Z5:1/s }))
VI*s*(s**2 + 2*s + 2)/(s**2 + 1)

Close. Appears you only missed including \$V_{i\left(s\right)}\$.
Anyway, I will leave it there. The big issue seems to be that you didn't get the right result for \$\det\left(D\right)\$.
